# Docker Swarm Network isolation

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, iptables, docker-network

I have following escenario:

- 3 hosts running swarm.
- 1 net used for interhost communication NetX(192.168.10.0/24)
- 2 net that have to be accessed Net1(192.168.30.0/24), Net2 (192.168.20.0/24)
- [image: Topology]

What I want is to create 2 services deployed in this 3 hosts with the next specs:

- Containers deployed by service 1 use its own Overlay net to communicate with other containers but only must communicate with Net1.
- Containers deployed by service 2 use its own Overlay net to communicate with other containers but only must communicate with Net2.

Topoly attached as image.

Please, Help!